# ValueError: Too many values to unpack in Python. Is this a network error?

Tags: python-2.7, networking, configuration

I get this python error when I try to run a script of covalent docking. However, if I'm connected to a new network, it runs for one time but gives the same error for the second run. I have no idea if this is a network problem or a python issue.

I have uninstalled the network driver for windows 7 64 bit and installed it back again. 
I have downloaded opencv and run cv.pyd. 
I am using a python version 2.7 32 bit with openbabel installed

```
C:\Users\najum.najumPC>C:\adCovalentDockResidue\adcovalent\prepareCovalent.py --ligand NMC.mol2 --ligindices 1,2 --receptor protein.pdb --residue B:CYS:199 --outputfile ligcovalent_NMC.pdb
Processing residue B:CYS:199
[start] output filename is: ligcovalent_NMC.pdb
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "C:\adCovalentDockResidue\adcovalent\prepareCovalent.py", line 1318, in < module>  x = CovalentDockingMaster()

File "C:\adCovalentDockResidue\adcovalent\prepareCovalent.py", line 870, in __init__self.start()

File "C:\adCovalentDockResidue\adcovalent\prepareCovalent.py", line 1261, in start self.processResidues()

File "C:\adCovalentDockResidue\adcovalent\prepareCovalent.py", line 1297, in processResidue aligner = self.x =CovalentDockingMaker(**self.alignerArgs)

File "C:\adCovalentDockResidue\adcovalent\prepareCovalent.py", line 229, in _init__self.initResidue()

File "C:\adCovalentDockResidue\adcovalent\prepareCovalent.py", line 266, in initResiduechain, res = string.split(":")
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a thing as a *network error* in your case...

If you analyze the Traceback you're getting it is telling you that the code is failing at line 266 of prepareCovalent.py  while doing `initResiduechain, res = string.split(":")`.

What does it mean?

It means that if we have a sample test string

```
test = "a:b:c:d"
```

operating a `test.split(":")` operation will return 4 values! (namely "a", "b", "c", "d")

Therefore, trying to do:

```
x, y = test.split(":")
```

will result in the error you're experiencing, the famous *too many values to unpack* error!

Otherwise, doing `x, y, z, t = test.split(":")` will succeed and you will not experience any error.

Anyway, I suggest you to reconsider the way you're doing that split operation considering a useful list that will encapsulate all the returned values like for example:

```
l = []
l = test.split(":")
```

This will work smoothly and you will be able to access all single elements just by simple indexing:

```
l[0]  # OUPUTS "a"
l[1]  # OUPUTS "b"
l[2]  # OUPUTS "c"
l[3]  # OUPUTS "d"
```